# Intersection of all positive powers of prime ideal in an integral domain with all ideals of finite height

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, ideals, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be an integral domain with every prime ideal having finite height. Then is $\bigcap_{n>1} P^n$ a prime ideal of $R$ for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$ ? If that is not true in general, then what if we also assume $R$ has finite dimension, or say very low dimension (say 1) ?

The Noetherian case obvious from Krull Intersection theorem, and so is the case when $R$ is s Prufer domain , due to Corollary 2.4 (a) of  https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v18/cjm1966v18.1024-1030.pdf .  So any possible counterexample would have to be non-Noetherian and non-Prufer.

Comment: I think the answer is no. I do not have the time now to check the details, but the $2$-dimensional valuation ring $S_{\mathfrak{n}}$ constructed in Proposition 2.9 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07407) seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: @Fred Rohrer : you claim to have a finite dimensional Valuation ring counterexample ..? That would be great ... it would say that we can't do any much better without Noetherian hypothesis ...

Comment: @Fred Rohrer : In this question body https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687037/an-example-of-prime-ideal-p-such-that-bigcap-n-1-inftypn-is-not-   though it is claimed the abswer is affirmative for Prufer domains , and Valuation rings are certainly Prufer domains...

Comment: Dear @misao, the claim in the question you mention is not true. See the remark after the proof of Theorem 2 in D. D. Anderson, _The Krull intersection theorem,_ Pacific J. Math. 57 (1975), 11-14.

Comment: Check "The Krull intersection theorem II" by D. D. Anderson, you'll find a couple of positive results. In particular if $P$ is principal, or invertible, or locally principal. Theorem 3.1 tells you that the intersection is a prime ideal whenever $R$ is a valuation domain.

Comment: @FredRohrer: in the remark to Theorem 2 of Anderson's first paper on Krull Intersection, the ideal $I$ itself is not necessarily taken to be prime ... but here I start with a prime ideal $P$ to begin with ...

Comment: @FredRohrer: As it appears, the claim is indeed true for Prufer domains ... Corollary 2.4 (a) in https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v18/cjm1966v18.1024-1030.pdf

Comment: Dear @misao, sorry for my second comment - I have overlooked that Anderson's remark is not about primes. And by Luc's comment it seems that what I hoped to be a counterexample doesn't work either...